# Python TypeError when using variable in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and I keep getting an error doing the simpliest thing.

I'm trying to use a variable in a regular expression and replace that with an *

the following gets me the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" and I can't tell why. this should be so simple.

```
import re
file = "my123filename.zip"
pattern = "123"
re.sub(r'%s', "*", file) % pattern
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in ?
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Any tips?

Comment: Did you mean this `re.sub(r'%s' % pattern, "*", file)`?

Comment: Whats your code in line l?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're problem is on this line:

```
re.sub(r'%s', "*", file) % pattern
```

What you're doing is replacing every occurance of `%s` with `*` in the text from the string `file` (in this case, I'd recommend renaming the variable `filename` to avoid shadowing the builtin `file` object and to make it more explicit what you're working with).  Then you're trying to replace the `%s` in the (already replaced) text with `pattern`.  However, `file`  doesn't have any format modifiers in it which leads to the `TypeError` you see.  It's basically the same as:

```
'this is a string' % ("foobar!")
```

which will give you the same error.

What you probably want is something more like:

```
re.sub(str(pattern),'*',file)
```

which is exactly equivalent to:

```
re.sub(r'%s' % pattern,'*',file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `re.sub(pattern, "*", file)`? Or maybe skip `re` altogether and just do `file.replace("123", "*")`.